# Trying to populate video file data to mysql database

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying on a mac to loop through all videos in a directory and add the details (Duration, size and time) of the file to a mysql db. But for some reason every time it fails on the mysql part.

If I take the mysql query generated by the script and run it on the mysql db it works fine. Can anyone help at all?

```
#!/bin/bash

OrDir="/Volumes/Misc/video"
find "$OrDir" -type f -exec /bin/bash -c \
    'name=$(basename "$1")
     name=${name%.*}
     duration=$( ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal "$1")
     hash=$( md5 "$1" | cut -f 4 -d " ")
     size=$( stat -f%z "$1")

     QUERY="UPDATE Video SET Duration=\"$duration\", Hash=\"$hash\", Bytes=$size WHERE Name=\"$name\" "
     echo "$QUERY \n"
     mysql --host=**.**.**.** --user=**** --password=****** **** << EOF
     $QUERY;
     EOF

     ' _ {} \;
```

The `*` are omitting sensitive data and are correct (they're used in another shell script with the same method that runs fine on the same server)

This is just part of a larger script which will then be combined once this works properly

Comment: Is the `EOF` indented? (if it is, don't indent it!)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It is exactly like above (indented to the find but not to the first line of the `EOF`)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf took away the indent and works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then remove the indentation: `EOF` must appear in the first column of your file!